# Moving tab is not working after some seconds on next button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have three tabs which add or remove active class on anchor tag not li when click on next button.

I tried that when I click on next button its disabled for some seconds then move to next tab button but issue is that moving is not working.

Here is code of html

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" style="width: 1050px">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#Race" data-toggle="tab">Race</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#Ace" data-toggle="tab">Ace</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#Deep" data-toggle="tab">Deep</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<!-- Race -->
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Race">

<button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
</div>
<!-- ACE -->
<div class="tab-pane" id="Ace">

    <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Next</button>
</div>
```

and jquery code

```
$(".btn-style").click(function () {
    $(".btn-style").prop("disabled", true );
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".btn-style").prop("disabled", false );


var target = $(".nav-pills li.nav-item a.active");
var sibbling;
if ($(this).text() === "Next") {
    sibbling = target.next();
} else {
    //sibbling = target.prev();
}
if (sibbling.is("li")) {
    target.removeClass("active")
    sibbling.addClass("active").children("a").tab("show");
}
}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Target` will be an array since there is more than 1 anchor with an `active` class.
You can try something easier like this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TMCDOS/pen/oyRoOw)

```
<style>
/* Checked Tabs */

.tabs-checked input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(1),
.tabs-checked input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(2),
.tabs-checked input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .tab:nth-of-type(3) 
{
  display: block;
}
.tab-area {
  width: 21%;
  margin: 2%;
}
input { 
  display: none;
}
.tab {
  clear: both;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 25px;
  display: none;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.tab-link:focus,
.tab-link:hover,
#tab-C:checked ~ label:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-B:checked ~ label:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-B:not(:checked) ~ #tab-C:not(:checked) ~ label:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #ddd;
}
.tab-link:focus:after,
.tab-link:hover:after,
#tab-C:checked ~ label:nth-of-type(3):after,
#tab-B:checked ~ label:nth-of-type(2):after,
#tab-B:not(:checked) ~ #tab-C:not(:checked) ~ label:nth-of-type(1):after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 55px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
}
.tab-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 55px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.tab-link:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #666;
}

.tab-link:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}
</style>
<form class="tab-area tabs-checked" name="temp">

    <input checked type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-A" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-B" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-C" value="3"/>

    <label class="tab-link" for="tab-A">Tab 1</label>
    <label class="tab-link" for="tab-B">Tab 2</label>
    <label class="tab-link" for="tab-C">Tab 3</label>

    <article class="tab">
        <h3>I love :checked. :checked is great. If only I could toggle any item and not just input elements we'd be golden.</h3>
    </article>
    <article class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</p>
    </article>
    <article class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</p>
    </article>

    <h2 class="title">Checked Tabs</h2>
    <p><strong>Independent, Default Selected</strong></p>
    <p>Works In: Chrome(latest), Opera(Latest), FireFox(Latest), IE9</p>

</form> 

<div >
<button onclick="doNext();" id="btn">NEXT</button>
</div>

<script>
function doNext()
{
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    document.temp.tab.value = document.temp.tab.value % 3 + 1;
    btn.disabled = false;
  },3000)
}
</script>
```

Comment: and I showing this error Cannot read property 'tab' of undefined

Comment: where you set the value of tab or length?

Comment: In Chrome the value of the currently checked item inside a radio-group can be obtained by the name of the radio-group like `document.formName.radioGroupName.value`. However, IE does not allow such syntax so you have to iterate over each radio-item and test whether its `checked` property is true or not in order to decide which item in the group is currently selected. Then you need to check the next item in the group or round over to the first one. The CSS rules ensure the corresponding tab will be made active according to the value of the radio-group.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways - I personally would go with the Vue.js framework instead of jQuery. But you may wish to explore some of the many jQuery-plugins for tabs, or even use the tab component from Bootstrap.